# invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference in go

Tags: go

i'm new in golang. i have a problem with my code.
this is my code looks like

```
type IUser interface {
    GetUser(name string) string
}

func GetUser(name string) string {
    return name
}

type User struct {
    Yy IUser
}

func main() {
    u := User{}
    fmt.Println(u.Yy.GetUser("bambang"))
}
```

when i run this code. error show error "invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference".
how to fix my code. for your info, `IUser interface` must include in User struct

Comment: `u.Yy` is not initialized. You have to create a new type implementing `GetUser` function, and initialize `u.Yy` to an instance of that type.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand. how to code this.?

Comment: `GetUser` is just a function in your code, not a method of `User`, so `User` doesn't implement `IUser`. Also don't name your interfaces `IType` - it makes your code look like C# code, not Go code. See https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialise `User` with `{}`, you're not initialising any of its members (`Yy` in this case), which means they all have default values. The default value for interfaces is `nil`.

You need to pass in an instance of a type that implements `IUser` to initialise `Yy`, but you haven't declared any implementing types in your code.

Here's a simple example with a `MySQLUser` type that implements `IUser`. Note how `Yy` is initialised.

```
type IUser interface {
    GetUser(name string) string
}

// MySQLUser implements IUser   
type MySQLUser struct {
}

func (u MySQLUser) GetUser(name string) string {
    return name
}

type User struct {
    Yy IUser
}

func main() {
    u := User{Yy: MySQLUser{}} // pass initialised IUser implementation
    fmt.Println(u.Yy.GetUser("bambang"))
}
```

You should probably review [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) or [Go by Example](https://gobyexample.com/) to understand interface fundamentals better.

Comment: Also, you should drop the `I` from the interface name. It's not idiomatic in Go. Try to think of a name that represents the purpose of the interface.

Comment: Ohhh. Oke. thanks. this is work for me. thank you very much.